# Running gulp server returns Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, gulp, centos7

I successfully run this pdf viewer from [mozilla/pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#online-demo) to my windows. But when I'm trying to install it to my centos 7 machine I'm getting this error when running gulp server.

```
[root@localhost pdf.js]# gulp server
/root/Desktop/node.prod/pdf.js/gulpfile.js:232
    output.library?.type === "module" ? { outputModule: true } : undefined;
                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at requireOrImport (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js:19:11)
    at execute (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js:37:3)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js:211:24)
```